# Vba Find Exact match

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to make VBA code to find columns with specific header and then perform some calculations on that column. My problem is that i have to look for specific words. In my case i have column headers like this:

```
Parametric STD-1 randomnumbers
Parametric STD-2 randomnumbers
STD-1 randomnumbers
STD-2 randomnumbers
```

Its easy to find Parametric STD-1 column address but when i look for STD-1 it will find Parametric. Problem is that i cant use exact match parameter because after STD-1/STD-2 there are some randomnumbers.

Do You have any idea what i could do to always find correct column address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `*` wildcard to find the first range with a value starting with  `STD-1` followed by *anything*

```
Range("A:A").Find("STD-1*")
```

For more inforomation about wildcard characters have a read of the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440632(v=office.12).aspx). You might also find the `#` operator useful.

Comment: Why not include a link to this page to your answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440632(v=office.12).aspx Like this the OP can adjust the wildcards to his / her liking for example `*STD-#*` to find `STD-1` as well as `STD-2`.

Comment: Thanks but i think this will also find "Parametric STD-1" in first place. is there option to make sure that there is no word before "STD-1" ?

Comment: @MatthewC. "I think this will..." sounds a lot like you haven't tested it. Why don't you try it out first and then tell us if it did/ didn't work. Just FYI I tested it with your data and it was working just fine :)

Comment: @CallumDA: So i use "STD-1*" with parameter LookAt:=XlWhole, thats correct? i have tested it and it works fine so far.

Comment: @MatthewC, That looks correct to me. I'm pleased it worked for you!